# ajax,I am getting same value when its has different value

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am clicking on different value but console.log give me same value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hkX1.jpg)

i also going html code which has different `value attribute` has different value but, its give me first value of attribute.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL4Ks.jpg)

actually, there 2 options for ajax. here is what i have tired.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $('.categoryList').click(function(){
          
          var cat_id = $(this).attr('value');
          var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/getSubcategory/"+cat_id;
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: url,
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(res)
              {
                var html = "";
                $.each(res, function (key, value) {
                     html += "<option  value="+key+">"+value+" </option>";
                });
                 $('#subcategory').html($(html).addClass('subcategoryList'));

              }
          });
        });

    });
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#subcategory').click(function() {

       var  subcat_id = $( this ).find( '.subcategoryList' ).attr('value');
          console.log(subcat_id);
          var url = "/api/getSubcategorytwo/"+subcat_id;
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: url,
              dataType: "JSON",
              success: function(res)
              {
                
                var html = "";
                $.each(res, function (key, value) {
                     html += "<option value="+key+">"+value+"</option>";
                });
                $("#subcategorytwo").html(html);

              }
          });
        });

    });
</script>
```

```html
                   <div class="col-md-4" >
              
                        @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <option  class="categoryList" value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->category}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    
                    </div>
                 
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <a  name="subcategory" id="subcategory" >
                         </a>
                        </div>
                  
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a name="subcategorytwo" id="subcategorytwo" >
                          <option value=""></option>
                        </a>
                        </div>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: How does your HTML code look like?

Comment: i dont understand how `option` tag came inside `a` tag, thats your first mistake.
`var  subcat_id = $( this ).find( '.subcategoryList' ).attr('value');` is always pointing to the first `option`, so it returns same value always. refer `select  --- option` documentation and make use of it

Answer (score 1):

The html code specified is all wrong. You either go with `<a />` anchor tag or `<select><option></option> </select>` select tag.

If you prefer `anchor` tag then you can get the click functionality, but in the html you will end up with a long list of anchors

If you choose the `select` tag, then you can invoke the on change event and get the selected value. You can use either of the following

[on change function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

[change event handler using jquery](https://api.jquery.com/change/)