# How can I get value of clicked attribute if class is same and value is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created code to get `attribute value` but i have same name class but value is different for that all options.

here is my `html code for` options

```js
$('#subcategory').click(function() {
    var  subcat_id = $( this ).find( '.subcategoryList' ).attr('value');
          console.log(subcat_id);     
    });
```

```html
<option name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
 <option value="3" class="subcategoryList">Village </option>
 <option value="4" class="subcategoryList">Real Estate </option>
</option>
```

This `html` also coming from JQuery function code as below:

```
... $.each(res, function (key, value) {
     html += "<option  value="+key+">"+value+" </option>";
    });
    $('#subcategory').html($(html).addClass('subcategoryList'));

    }
...
```

Comment: There is no AJAX anywhere in the code you've posted. Did you mean JQuery?

Comment: Yes its `J query` @ScottMarcus

Comment: I believe you'll want a [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element around the `<option>` elements.

Comment: You can't have `options` nested within other `options`.

Comment: Actually I dont get you @ScottMarcus

Comment: I wonder if the intention was to use an optgroup.  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-optgroup-element

Comment: Actually i dont want dropdown, yes i want to `select` but not without dropdown option. @showdev

Comment: you have an invalid html. `<option name="subcategory" id="subcategory">` should be  `<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">` This is what @ScottMarcus is talking about. And a select whitout dropdown options makes no sense at all

Comment: `<option>` is only used with dropdown lists (`select`). If that's not what you want then a different tag must be used. What do you want.

Comment: @ScottMarcus typo fixed, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't have `option` elements nested in other `option` elements. They should be nested within a `select` element.

That being the case, you'd want to work with the `change` event, not the `click` event.

And finally, this is a simple operation that just needs to look at the `value` of the `select` after a `change`. No JQuery needed.

```js
document.getElementById("subcategory").addEventListener("change", function() {
   console.log(this.value);    
});
```

```html
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
 <option value="3" class="subcategoryList">Village </option>
 <option value="4" class="subcategoryList">Real Estate</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @user10522002 Yes, but you didn't say what you **do** want. The code you are using is **ONLY** used to create dropdown boxes. I'm providing you an answer that uses the code you showed. If you want something else, show some different code.

Comment: `size="2"` would remove the "dropdown" part.

Comment: @Taplar Yes, but it is still unclear if this is even what the OP is going for. I have a feeling that he may want radio buttons.

Comment: Actually I am trying to make,... options depends on another. OUTPUT: Car->All Card->New Car @ScottMarcus Olx. has category. i am making same like it.

Comment: @user10522002 That doesn't answer my very simple question. What kind of user interface element do you want (radio buttons, list of choices, checkboxes, etc.)?

Comment: here is corrected link for complete code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577262/ajax-i-am-getting-same-value-when-its-has-different-value

Comment: That question appears to be appending `<option>` tags to an `<a>` tag.  That is also invalid

Comment: @user10522002 Not sure why you won't just answer this question instead of showing invalid code. What kind of UI element do you want to have?

Answer (score 0):

or if you want the jquery version for that

```js
$('#subcategory').change(function() {
    var subcat_id = $(this).val();
    console.log(subcat_id);     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
 <option value="3" class="subcategoryList">Village </option>
 <option value="4" class="subcategoryList">Real Estate </option>
</select>
```

Note that the class for each option is completely useless here for your purpose